# External Connection to School Ubuntu Server

Tags: ssh, google-chrome, vpn, remote-desktop

I have a Ubuntu machine in school and I can only ssh to the machine only in the school network.
(while it is a public IP address)

However, as I installed a chrome remote desktop, I can connect to the machine from everywhere.

How is this possible?

Comment: There may be several possible reasons. For example, Chrome Remote Desktop uses a different port than ssh. If you want ssh access from the internet, ask your school's IT department for assistance. DON'T try to haywire something yourself or workaround their policies. That's how folks get their server kicked off the network entirely (and perhaps themself suspended).

Answer (score 0):

You need to talk to the administrator of the server about opening it up to the outside world. I would think making that case for an exemption to their access policies will be a hard one. If they do not allow it now, I fail to see you convincing them to do for you only.